Hunger, food, eating tag?
I feel as if we should have a tag for questions related to hunger, food, and eating. I.e., why do we like certain foods? What is the effect of food on us? How to regulate food intake? etc.
We do have a perception tag but it feels a bit general to me.
Some Existing Questions

What is the reward mechanism for eating spicy foods?
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4046/what-are-the-effects-of-eating-huge-amounts-of-food-in-short-periods-of-time-on
Have there been any studies which report a positive correlation between eating certain foods and reported sleep disturbances?
What happens when a person "imagines" how food could taste like just from looking at it?
Does introducing an element of play, hunt, or competition make feeding more rewarding?

Question

Do people think we need such a tag?
If so, what should the tag be?


[tag:perception] is too general I agree, but I will let others propose an actual improvement.

feeding would be the most general in my mind, as it would lasso in animal behaviors as well.

Sounds good to me. And we can tag synonym the rest.

http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v450/n7166/abs/nature06212.html For context

given the two downvotes and the desire for consensus on meta, I've unselected this as an answer. That said, I think the main thing is to have "a tag" to capture this stuff. If a clear alternative emerges through voting I'll update the tag.

"Feeding" or "food and eating" seem good to me. Yes, each human natural biological process or activity should have its tag. Like, sleeping, sexuality, etc...

I think the main thing is that we have such a tag.
My feeling that of the three (hunger, eating, and food), that a "food" tag would be most appropriate as it is probably the most relevant aspect. Many questions might pertain to the effect or desire for particular foods. Eating is arguably more concerned with the process of consumption, and hunger relates more to the motivation. 
